# Login with php in android

Tags: php, android, mysql

Hi I am new to android and I am trying to connect android to MySQL with php. I want to create a login system where only admin can login. 
Below is my code

```
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.
        Boolean s = true;
        String link = "http://localhost/eKos/login.php";

        try{
            URL url = new URL(link);
            String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                    URLEncoder.encode(mUsername, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                    URLEncoder.encode(mPassword, "UTF-8");

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            // Read Server Response
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }

            if (sb.toString() != "Login Successful"){
                s = false;
            }

            } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.print("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
            return s;
    }
```

However, it seems like variable s is not modified at all inside the try block since this function always returns true.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  if (!(sb.toString()).equals("Login Successful")){
            s = false;
        }

        } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.print("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        s = false;
    }
        return s;
```

Also print your server response whether it has `Login Successful` string in it..
and check if any exception is thrown

Answer (score 0):

Are you using volley?

There is a great tutorial for this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxffHgiJ64M&list=PLe60o7ed8E-TztoF2K3y4VdDgT6APZ0ka

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you Use "retrofit2" library?! it's far better, faster and easier than AsyncTask or Volly and it doesn't have the complexity of two mentioned libraries. You can use the links blow for more informarion:
https://square.github.io/retrofit/
And
http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/